# Is it possible to test throughput without server cooperation?

Tags: bandwidth, iperf

To measure throughput between two points in a network using iperf, you have to run iperf at one point in server mode. My question is, is there a tool I can use to measure this bandwidth without running anything at the server? That is, without an open TCP port? Maybe by sending bursts of ICMP echo request packets (which makes a reasonable assumption that an ICMP echo response will be received.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible to get any meaningful data without something actually running on the server which you can exchange packets with.

...and no, ICMP packets will not give you any useful information about bandwidth between endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

If the far side is a webserver that you can at least upload an image to, you could upload an image with a known file size, then write a script on your client to download the image over and over and over again and record how long it takes for the file to be downloaded.  With that time and the known file size, you could put together a relative bandwidth graph over time.

Comment: It is not a web server because that requires an open TCP port and the problem states that open TCP ports cannot be assumed.